# How to make peel effect in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making a project in codeigniter. My design and development section is ready. All i need to do is to make a peel effect in my index page. How could i do that???
Please help.
Thanx in advance

Comment: You need to try to do it yourself (thats how you learn). Then we can help you when you have a problem along the way.

Comment: if this question had been asked in 09/10, it would have 200+ upvotes, and not have been closed as off topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <style type='text/css'>
 img { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
 #pageflip {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0; top: 0;
 float: right;
 }
 #pageflip img {
 width: 50px; height: 52px;
 z-index: 99;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0; top: 0;
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
 #pageflip .back-img {
 width: 50px; height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0; top: 0;z-index:98;
 background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HAvgxzbgzPg/UE-KcuJyFWI/AAAAAAAAA5w/2wb-        
 jmsGcHc/s1600/mini_rss.png) no-repeat right top #fff;
 }
 </style><a href='http://realcombiz.com'><img src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RikrI-  
 c_pyQ/T2DTcP6aMvI/AAAAAAAAAL0/H6v7PVoHM_w/s1600/1x1juice.png'/></a><script         
 type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
//Page Flip on hover
 $(&quot;#pageflip&quot;).hover(function() {
 $(&quot;#pageflip img , .back-img&quot;).stop()
 .animate({
 width: &#39;307px&#39;,
 height: &#39;319px&#39;
 }, 500);
```

Copy the following code Inside/after  or search for "

```
  <div id='pageflip'>
  <a href=' http://feeds.feedburner.com/realcombiz '><img alt='Realcombiz'      
     src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_1fRuBdlSpLw/TJcc3k62mWI/AAAAAAAAAps/uSj6nCe_CB4/s1600/page_f    lip.png'/></a>
<div class='back-img'/>
</div>
```

Replace http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HAvgxzbgzPg/UE-KcuJyFWI/AAAAAAAAA5w/2wb- jmsGcHc/s1600/mini_rss.png with your preferred image link, it is rss icon by default.
Replace http://feeds.feedburner.com/realcombiz with your feed link, or change it to any link you want to point your image to
Preview your changes and click "SAVE TEMPLATE".

Comment: your jquery code is not working

Comment: Mention the error....

Comment: "#pageflip .back-img" there should be a comma between these two classes. Then in jquery i am not getting what is "&quot" used.

Answer (score 0):

In this page they listed out 10 different jQuery Page Peel Plugins already available.

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-page-peel-plugins/

You can try any one of these.

Comment: Ya i have seen that but none of them are supporting in codeigniter

Comment: Page Peel Effect is on Front-end. What is the relation with CodeIgniter?

Comment: Yes but still its not working...

Comment: What you tried? and What is not working?

Comment: i had applied the plugins given there but nothing is happening. Not even image is coming